# If ElseIf Else error in random events code

Tags: php

Here is my full code, This worked perfectly fine when I had all elseif as if and all else as elseif.

But I need the first if statement to run before anything. that way if they had less then the minimum turns they will not be aloud to continue. 
here is the error i am getting...
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF

**CODE**

```
<?php

$ingame = "*";
require 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/modzoideditables.php';
include 'includes/zoideditables.php';
include 'includes/offdefvalues.php';
$turns = 5;
$turns2 = 10;
$zoidmany = 1;
$zoidmany2 = 2;
$excav1 = 1;
$excav2 = 0;
$goldgive1 = 500;
$goldgive2 = 700;
$goldgive3 = 1000;
$goldgive4 = 1500;
$goldgive5 = 2000;
$fight1 = 20000;
$fight2 = 27000;
$fight3 = 31000;
$goldtake1 = 250;
$goldtake2 = 500;
$goldtake3 = 750;
$goldtake4 = 1000;
$miner = 5;

    $rand = rand( 1, 22 );
if ( $turns > $user['uAttackTurns'] ) {
        echo "You don't have enough turns.";
}   
    $rand = rand( 1, 22 );
 elseif ( $excav1 > $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 1 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uGatlingzaberfangweap=uGatlingzaberfangweap+$zoidmany,uExcavation2=uExcavation2-$excav1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/>You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
    else ( $rand == 2 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uGatlingzaberfangweap=uGatlingzaberfangweap+$zoidmany2,uExcavation2=uExcavation2-$excav1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany2?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/>You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php

        }
        elseif ( $excav2 = $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 1 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/> But you have no excavation tool! You cannot excavate</b></center><br /><?php
     ?><center><b>Tools needed: 1 <img src="<?=$excav_image2?>"/> </b></center><br /><?php
    }
    else ( $rand == 2 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany2?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/> But you have no excavation tool! You cannot excavate</b></center><br /><?php
?><center><b>Tools needed: 1 <img src="<?=$excav_image2?>"/> </b></center><br /><?php

    }
            elseif ( $rand == 3 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uWeapon42=uWeapon42+$zoidmany,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns+'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>You see something shiny in the distance, What is that you wonder?</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just found a fully working <?=$wp_42_nm?>!<img src="<?=$wp_42_image?>"/></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>No need for excavation tools here, This bad boy runs!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
         elseif ( $fight2 > $defensetotal ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 4 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive3,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a group of <?=$wp_43_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_43_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>You managed to fend them off and scored a nice <?=$goldgive3?> gold!</b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight2?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $fight2 < $defensetotal ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 4 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$goldtake2,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a pack of <?=$wp_43_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_43_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>Your defense couldn't hold up to their might! You loose <?=$goldtake2?> Gold!</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight2?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
             elseif ( $fight1 > $defensetotal ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 5 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive2,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a group of <?=$wp_32_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_32_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>You managed to fend them off and scored a nice <?=$goldgive2?> gold!</b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight1?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $fight1 < $defensetotal ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 5 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$goldtake1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a pack of <?=$wp_32_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_32_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>Your defense couldn't hold up to their might! You loose <?=$goldtake1?> Gold!</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight1?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $rand == 6 || $rand == 7 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$gold1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just got ambushed. You loose 50 gold!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
            elseif ( $rand == 8 || $rand == 9 || $rand == 10 || $rand == 11  ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>After a long hard journey you come up empty handed!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $excav1 > $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 12 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uEleshotbrhinosweap=uEleshotbrhinosweap+$zoidmany,uExcavation2=uExcavation2-$excav1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap6_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap6_image?>"/>You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $excav2 = $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 12 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap6_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap6_image?>"/> But you have no excavation tool! You cannot excavate</b></center><br /><?php
     ?><center><b>Tools needed: 1 <img src="<?=$excav_image2?>"/> </b></center><br /><?php
    }
         elseif ( $fight3 > $defensetotal ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 13 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive4,uWeapon48=uWeapon48+$zoidmany,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a group of <?=$wp_48_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_48_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>You managed to fend them off and scored a nice <?=$goldgive4?> gold!</b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You also managed to take a fully working <?=$wp_48_nm?>, <img src="<?=$wp_48_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight3?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $fight3 < $defensetotal ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 13 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$goldtake3,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a pack of <?=$wp_48_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_48_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>Your defense couldn't hold up to their might! You loose <?=$goldtake3?> Gold!</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight3?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
        elseif ( $rand == 14 || $rand == 15 || $rand == 16 || $rand == 17  ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$goldgive1?> Gold. You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
        elseif ( $rand == 18 || $rand == 19 || $rand == 20 || $rand == 21  ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uMiners=uMiners+$miner,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just found <?=$miner?> miners, your forcing them to join you!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
elseif ( $turns > $user['uAttackTurns'] ) {
}   
   else ( $rand == 22 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-$turns,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just lost an additional <?=$turns?>. Better luck next time!</b></center><br /><?php
    }

require 'includes/footer.php';

?>
```

**And BELOW IS THE WORKING CODE, THE ONLY PROBLEM I HAVE IS, WHEN THEY GET BELOW THE TURN LIMIT THEY CAN STILL USE IT CAUSING THEM TO GO INTO NEGATIVE TURNS.**

```
    <?php

$ingame = "*";
require 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/modzoideditables.php';
include 'includes/zoideditables.php';
include 'includes/offdefvalues.php';
$turns = 5;
$turns2 = 10;
$zoidmany = 1;
$zoidmany2 = 2;
$excav1 = 1;
$excav2 = 0;
$goldgive1 = 500;
$goldgive2 = 700;
$goldgive3 = 1000;
$goldgive4 = 1500;
$goldgive5 = 2000;
$fight1 = 20000;
$fight2 = 27000;
$fight3 = 31000;
$goldtake1 = 250;
$goldtake2 = 500;
$goldtake3 = 750;
$goldtake4 = 1000;
$miner = 5;
    $rand = rand( 1, 22 );
if ( $turns > $user['uAttackTurns'] ) {
        echo "You don't have enough turns.";
}   
    $rand = rand( 1, 22 );
 if ( $excav1 > $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 1 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uGatlingzaberfangweap=uGatlingzaberfangweap+$zoidmany,uExcavation2=uExcavation2-$excav1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/>You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $rand == 2 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uGatlingzaberfangweap=uGatlingzaberfangweap+$zoidmany2,uExcavation2=uExcavation2-$excav1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany2?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/>You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php

        }
        if ( $excav2 = $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 1 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/> But you have no excavation tool! You cannot excavate</b></center><br /><?php
     ?><center><b>Tools needed: 1 <img src="<?=$excav_image2?>"/> </b></center><br /><?php
    }
    elseif ( $rand == 2 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany2?> <?=$mz_weap3_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap3_image?>"/> But you have no excavation tool! You cannot excavate</b></center><br /><?php
?><center><b>Tools needed: 1 <img src="<?=$excav_image2?>"/> </b></center><br /><?php

    }
            if ( $rand == 3 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uWeapon42=uWeapon42+$zoidmany,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns+'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>You see something shiny in the distance, What is that you wonder?</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just found a fully working <?=$wp_42_nm?>!<img src="<?=$wp_42_image?>"/></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>No need for excavation tools here, This bad boy runs!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
         if ( $fight2 > $defensetotal ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 4 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive3,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a group of <?=$wp_43_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_43_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>You managed to fend them off and scored a nice <?=$goldgive3?> gold!</b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight2?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    if ( $fight2 < $defensetotal ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 4 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$goldtake2,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a pack of <?=$wp_43_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_43_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>Your defense couldn't hold up to their might! You loose <?=$goldtake2?> Gold!</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight2?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
             if ( $fight1 > $defensetotal ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 5 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive2,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a group of <?=$wp_32_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_32_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>You managed to fend them off and scored a nice <?=$goldgive2?> gold!</b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight1?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    if ( $fight1 < $defensetotal ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 5 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$goldtake1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a pack of <?=$wp_32_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_32_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>Your defense couldn't hold up to their might! You loose <?=$goldtake1?> Gold!</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight1?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    if ( $rand == 6 || $rand == 7 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$gold1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just got ambushed. You loose 50 gold!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
            if ( $rand == 8 || $rand == 9 || $rand == 10 || $rand == 11  ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>After a long hard journey you come up empty handed!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
    if ( $excav1 > $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 12 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uEleshotbrhinosweap=uEleshotbrhinosweap+$zoidmany,uExcavation2=uExcavation2-$excav1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap6_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap6_image?>"/>You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
    if ( $excav2 = $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 12 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$zoidmany?> <?=$mz_weap6_nm?>. <img src="<?=$mz_weap6_image?>"/> But you have no excavation tool! You cannot excavate</b></center><br /><?php
     ?><center><b>Tools needed: 1 <img src="<?=$excav_image2?>"/> </b></center><br /><?php
    }
         if ( $fight3 > $defensetotal ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 13 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive4,uWeapon48=uWeapon48+$zoidmany,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a group of <?=$wp_48_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_48_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>You managed to fend them off and scored a nice <?=$goldgive4?> gold!</b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You also managed to take a fully working <?=$wp_48_nm?>, <img src="<?=$wp_48_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /> <?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight3?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
    if ( $fight3 < $defensetotal ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 13 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold-$goldtake3,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You were attacked by a pack of <?=$wp_48_nm?>'s <img src="<?=$wp_48_image?>"/>.</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>Your defense couldn't hold up to their might! You loose <?=$goldtake3?> Gold!</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>YOUR DEFENSE: <?=$defensetotal?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>THEIR ATTACK: <?=$fight3?></b></center><br /></b></center><br /><?php
    }
        if ( $rand == 14 || $rand == 15 || $rand == 16 || $rand == 17  ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET ugold=ugold+$goldgive1,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just stumbled across <?=$goldgive1?> Gold. You decide to keep it!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
        if ( $rand == 18 || $rand == 19 || $rand == 20 || $rand == 21  ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uMiners=uMiners+$miner,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just found <?=$miner?> miners, your forcing them to join you!</b></center><br /><?php
    }
if ( $turns > $user['uAttackTurns'] ) {
}   
   elseif ( $rand == 22 ) {
        $rand_cash = rand( 1, 50 );
        $db->query( "UPDATE users SET uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-$turns,uAttackTurns=uAttackTurns-'$turns' WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );

 ?><center><b>This Exploration costed you 5 Turns</b></center><br /><?php
        ?><center><b>You just lost an additional <?=$turns?>. Better luck next time!</b></center><br /><?php
    }

require 'includes/footer.php';

?>
```

Comment: Does it give a line number? That would help trying to track it down. Also, `  else ( $rand == 12 ) {` isn't going to work - is that supposed to be another `elseif`? There are a few of those in your code.

Comment: You may just want to remove your first test code because everyone thinks that's what you are having your problems with.

Comment: Glad it is you that has to maintain that code not me.  Usually when I start to think "if elseif" I need to re-factor my code with better structure/methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users are getting more turns because you aren't doing anything that prevents them from doing so. Put the rest of your code in using `else {}` after the first `if` statement:

```
if( $turns > $user['uAttackTurns'] ) {
    echo "You don't have enough turns.";
}
else {

    /*** Carry on As Usual ***/
}
```

This will prevent any other code from running if `$turns` **is greater than** `$user['uAttackTurns']`.

Also, you don't have to redefine `$rand = rand( 1, 22);`. You declare it once above, and again after the first if statement.

Comment: This was actually what fixed my problem! Thank you so much. The ELSE was what I need to make everything fit right in place like a nice puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

That random shoud be inside, you can'do this

```
if (condition)
 {
 //code
 }
 //another code
elseif (condition)
 {
 //code
 }
```

so you should change your code here:

```
if ( $turns > $user['uAttackTurns'] ) {
        echo "You don't have enough turns.";
        $rand = rand( 1, 22 );
}       
 elseif
 //code...
```

EDIT:

There is no condition after else, so

```
else(condition)
{
//code
}
```

will produce another error. Last else will be done if everything else failed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I ended up learning a good amount during this. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty concise.
"unexpected T_ELSEIF" - how else can I make this simpler? There is  an elseif that was not expected, should not be there, is in the wrong place...

You didn't give a line or code where it occurs, but I'm guessing it's this:

```
if ( $turns > $user['uAttackTurns'] ) {
        echo "You don't have enough turns.";
}   
    $rand = rand( 1, 22 );
 elseif ( $excav1 > $user['uExcavation2'] ) {
}
```

So to do else, elseif, etc, you need to follow from one curly bracket to another..

```
if (something)
  {
    whatever
  }
elseif (something else)
 {
   whatever else
 }
```

Also, I don't see you actually using your `$rand` var inside the if/elseif, so is there some missing code? If you need it on each if/else, put it inside the elseif.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the statement `$rand = rand( 1, 22 );` in between your first 'if' and the first 'elseif'. The 'elseif' needs to directly follow an 'if' with no statements in between.